# Permalink Options does not change

Tags: permalinks

Im trying to change my permalink options, when i click save , it redirects me to my index page and the permalink option stay the same !! Could some one help me ? Thanks. I have already deactivate the plugins and i got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Apache web server have mod_rewrite.

Create .htaccess on your wordpress root directory with following content (or add these to existing .htaccess file):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```